# DevExpress Reporting: What technical points I have to consider?

Tags: devexpress

I am now to reporting and I have to prepare myself to able to make reports. So, I want to know What technical points I have to consider while reporting in XtraReports of DevExpress? And what topics hould I cover?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look this webinar which covers a lot and also shows off some of the report generation:

DevExpress Webinar: XtraReports - Resolving the Reporting Dilemma
http://tv.devexpress.com/XtraReportsWebinar1.movie